# Composite transformations intuition

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm struggling to understand composite transformations.
If we let $f(x) = \sin x$, and then draw the graph $f(2x)$.
Why is it that when we translate $f(2x)$ by $\pi/4$ units to the right, one of the $x$ intercepts to the graph becomes $- \pi / 4$.
I understand why this happens algebraically, but can someone please help me understand the graphical intuition behind this?

Comment: Better for me to respond to the (underlying) *broader* question.  Suppose that $~f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R},~$ and you take the graph of $~f(x)~$ and **translate** it $~k~$ units to the right $~: ~k \in \Bbb{R^+}.~$  What are you then graphing ?  **Answer** : Assuming that by **translate** you mean that the entire graph is being shifted $~k~$ units to the right, you are (in effect) now graphing the function $~g(x) = f(x-k).$  That is, the *height* of the graph $~g(x)~$ at $~[x = (x_0 + k)]~$ equals the height of the graph $~f(x)~$ at $~[x = (x_0)].$